# Resize rectangle with Text

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to create a custom drop-down box with text inside. The problem is, when I resize my `Rectangle` to fold it the `Text` stays on screen.

```
Rectangle {
    id: dropdown
    height: 200
    width: 200
    color: "red"

    Behavior on height {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 1000;
            easing.type: Easing.InQuad
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: text
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        text: "foobar"
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have it thanks to jbache.

I need to put `clip:true` inside `dropdown`. According to the documentation of [`clip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop):

> This property holds whether clipping is enabled. The default clip value is false.
>   If clipping is enabled, an item will clip its own painting, as well as the painting of its children, to its bounding rectangle.

Hence, by setting the property to `true`, I can ensure that also the child `Text` will be correctly hidden on drop-down dismiss.